# How many objects of angular component gets created

Tags: angular

Question 1: let's say I have a footer component and I am using it in other 3 components. How many objects of footer component will get created?

Question 2: suppose I have 3 tabs on page and in every tab click, I am calling component using its selector. How many objects of that component will get created?

Answer (score 0):

Angular will create a new component instance for every time you use it in your html file. So if you have three places where you use the footer component, angular will create three footer objects. Same answer goes for second question.